# Should I contact editor to inquire about the revised manuscript?

Tags: peer-review

I submitted a revised manuscript on 19/2/2023. The paper changed to With Editor after few days (2 times) and changed to Under review on 10/3/2023 after I sent an inquiry about the status (this time, EiC told that the previous Editor was retired, and the paper was assigned to a new Editor). The system showed that the re-review invitation was sent to 2 reviewers and one reviewer quickly returned the evaluation on 16/3/2023. However, the second review still do not accept the re-review invitation since 10/3. I tried to contact the journal support, but nothing changed. I understand the review time may be long but for the revision it may not because the reviewer already known the manuscript. But here, it almost 3 weeks, but the review did not respond the re-review invitation. Should I contact Editor to inquire the revised manuscript again?

Comment: Just be patient.    Reviewers and editors are usually volunteer.   I for example only look at my assignments once a month.

Comment: Thank VitaminE. I know both Editor and reviewers are volunteer and very busy. Here, I concern about that it has been almost three weeks without an acceptance from the reviewer since the invitation was sent. And it looks like he/she will not re-review it forever. Besides, I saw some comments that the typical time for invitation is within 2 weeks. Thus, I wonder if I should contact editor regarding this issue.